# LoadLibrary and SetWindowsHookEx inquiry

Tags: c++, windows

I wanted to make sure i fully understand those API functions. If I have an application and a dll where i created a thread. I load this dll inside the application with LoadLibrary function.  Does it mean that this dll thread is now a thread of that application?

P.S The thread in the dll created via exported function if that matters.
Thanks.

Comment: Was about to vote to close, but @DavidW managed to answer you question quite well. My 0.02 : do not create a thread in DllMain and begin your journey into threads using a single self contained exe.

Comment: I wrote that i create one via exported function.

Answer (score 2):

Understand that threads are an element of an executing process - there's no real notion of a DLL "owning" a thread. The code that *starts* the thread may well have originated from a function call in code *contained in* a DLL, but the *process* that loaded the library is the one that owns the thread. Loading the library merely makes the code in that library available to the calling process dynamically (at runtime).